# Will increasing server memory help gaining IIS stack memory?

Tags: iis

Currently my application have few long running processes. Sometimes IIS getting crash due to Stack Overflow Exception while running these processes.

Increasing server spec can really help to solve this problem.

I need some advise on this.

Answer (score 4):

Not really. Seriously. I never had proper programmed code have a stackoverflow exception.

Instead of throwing hardware, start debugging. You likely have some rarely used code path that throws a stackoverflow exception because of a programming bug under certain circumstances. Regardless how much memory you have.

A debugger and 5 minutes work will at least find that.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing **system memory** with **stack size**. Since 2003, the stack size of IIS is set to 256k. You can set it to 1 MB (the pre 2003 standard) by using editbin. This can solve many Stack Overflow Exception errors.

```
EDITBIN /STACK:1048576 w3wp.exe
```